# gnuplot error:"Tic label does not evaluate as string!" in bar chart

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I'm working on Gnuplot 4.6 patch 4.
I want to create the bar chart with palette. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808335/color-bars-in-different-colors-for-some-specific-values-in-gnuplot) but I got error:

```
Tic label does not evaluate as string!
```

Yes, the different with the reference that I mentioned above are the xtics. My graph uses string in xtics.

Here is my sample data:

```
off 100.0
gpl 60.0
docs    99
vim 9.4
box 95
goo 60
ama 99.9
eba 99.98
```

and my plot file is:

```
set term pos eps font 20
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set boxwidth 0.75
set format y "%.0f%%"
set style fill solid border -1

set xtics font "Times-Roman, 15" rotate by 45 right
#set xtics center offset 0,-1
set ytics font "Times-Roman, 15" 

set palette defined ( 0 "#FFFFFF",\
                      1 "#FFCCCC",\
                      2 "#FF9999 ",\
                      3 "#FF6666",\
                      4 "#FF3333",\
                      5 "#FF0000",\
                      6 "#CC0000",\
                      7 "#C00000",\
                      8 "#B00000",\
                      9 "#990000",\
                      10 "#A00000")

set ylabel "Percentages"
#set xlabel "Services"
set yrange [70:100]
set output 'a2.eps'
plot 'a2.dat' \
    using ($2):xtic(1):($2<=10 ? 0 : $2<=20 ? 1 : 2) t '' with boxes palette
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xtic` label part should always be the last in a `using` statement. Also, when using the `boxes` plotting style you must specify x, y and color values:

```
plot 'a2.dat' \
    using 0:2:($2<=10 ? 0 : $2<=20 ? 1 : 2):xtic(1) t '' with boxes palette
```

Note, that `with boxes` overwrites the `histogram` style you set earlier. Also, the values given in the palette aren't absolute values, but those color values are scaled to accomodate your effictive color range of [0:2].

Comment: very useful. Thank you @Christoph..
yes I forgot remove the histogram, I used to use histogram and now I change to boxes palette. Is it possible change the palette from the number to be string?